# What is the name of the field of maths that includes altering the order of functions within a composite function

Tags: functions

I am doing a some work with composite functions. I have some functions say f(x) and g(x) p(x) q(x). I end up with strings of function applications to x such as ppqfgggqffggggf(x).

I would refer to this in my notes as something like p^2qfg^3qf^2g^4f(x) although I do not know if this is standard  notation.

I want to explore altering the order of the functions so that I can take the composite function above and recast it by doing something like collecting the p, q, f and g functions together.

Something like (say) fg^3fg^4f(x)=r(x)s(x).

Ultimately I want to be able to take an expression like fg^nfg^mf(x) and recast it as something of the form (say) r(m,n,x). This may well be possible for some functions and not others.

I am managing to make some progress but thought a text on function composition would help. I can't find out what this area of maths is even called beyond composite functions and a search for "composite functions" returns loads of pretty low level stuff.

I really do know how to differentiate a composite function which seems to be a massive issue on "the google".

The question (thanks for reading this far) is

"What is the name of the field of maths that looks at multiple level composite functions?" (as described above)

Failing that, what is the name of the field of mathematics that includes this.

Comment: Usually the names of mathematical fields are for broader and more general topics, like analysis, number theory, algebraic geometry, differential geometry, PDEs, representation theory and so on.

Comment: I have edited the question. I do not mind if the thing I am looking at is part of a wider field. Any reference to this general area (whether or not it is within some other area) would be great.

Comment: ""What is the name of the field of maths that looks at multiple level composite functions?" Answer: no field at all. It belongs to calculus, though. You cound also ask for the name of the field of mathematics that looks to multiple composition of integers. Also I would say, multiple composition of integers is no area, but belongs somehow to elementary number theory.

Comment: If all the functions have the same domain and codomain, we can consider this a module. (If all are bijective, it's a group.) Then the question of whether or not $f \circ g = g \circ f$ is whether the two module elements "commute". But module theory won't make use of properties of the functions themselves, just considering them as mostly unknown things that can be combined.

Comment: @Dietrich Well asking Questions is an Art. 
I am not sure that composite functions is within calculus although I would accept there is an intersection. 
What I am after really is a decent search term to find some references although some decent references would be fine.

Comment: @aschepler Mmm, group theory might have some references. That's a start. Thanks

Comment: nerak, more important is what you are going to do with these multiple function compositions. For integers we would apply this to divisibility problems or prime number issues, perhaps. You should provide more context for your applications.

Comment: @Dietrich. You may well be right but I am having some fun with this which is the main thing.
 In my experience, if you give the complete context of a question then someone will respond with a downvote and a comment to the effect that you should not do it like that. 

Maybe that's just Computer Scientists though ;-)

Comment: Well, you have objects (functions), one operation (composition, $\circ$) and the associativity law is satisfied, so you are perhaps dealing with a [semigroup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semigroup) - or, if you remember that the identity map acts as a neutral element - with a [monoid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monoid).

Comment: @Stinking Bishop. Thanks. I think group theory based searches is the way to go.